# How to get all combination from bits?

Tags: c#, networking, binary, bit

I'm making program that will write all possible subnetworks and hosts range.
For example I have 4 bits for  subnetworks, so I need to write all posible combination.
Input: 4 : output(array): 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100,0101...1111 the one i've made is too slow: increment decimal number -> convert to binary, I want to do it without conversion.

Here is my incorrect algorithm, but it works

```
   public List<string> getAllCombination(int bits)
    {
        List<string> strarray = new List<string>();
        string temp = "";
        //make 1st word 
        for(int i = 0;i< bits;i++)
        {
            temp += "0";
        }
        strarray.Add(temp);
        int loops = (int)Math.Pow(2, bits) - 1;
        for(int i = 0; i< loops;i++)
        {
            int smallestBitPosition = -1;
            //find last 1
            for(int j = temp.Length -1 ; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (temp[j] == '1')
                    smallestBitPosition = j;

            }
            StringBuilder temp1 = new StringBuilder(temp);
            //if there are no 1 
            if (smallestBitPosition == -1)
            {
                temp1[temp1.Length - 1] = '1';
                temp = temp1.ToString();
                strarray.Add(temp);
                continue;
            }

            int lastZeroPosition = -1;
            //find last zero
            for (int j = smallestBitPosition; j< temp.Length; j++)
            {
                if (temp[j] == '0')
                    lastZeroPosition = j;
            }
            //if theres no 0 
            if(lastZeroPosition == -1 )
            {
                temp1[smallestBitPosition - 1] = '1';
                for(int g = smallestBitPosition ; g  < temp.Length; g++ )
                {
                    temp1[g] = '0';
                }
                temp = temp1.ToString();
                strarray.Add(temp);
                continue;
            }
            //i dont even know how to describe this, without this part it makes for example 101 -> 111, when it should be 110
            else if ((lastZeroPosition + 1 != bits) && temp[lastZeroPosition + 1] == '1')
            {
                temp1[lastZeroPosition] = '1';
                for (int g = lastZeroPosition + 1; g < temp.Length; g++)
                {
                    temp1[g] = '0';
                }
                temp = temp1.ToString();
                strarray.Add(temp);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                temp1[lastZeroPosition] = '1';

                temp = temp1.ToString();
                strarray.Add(temp);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return strarray;
```

Comment: You are asking someone to do your work. First benchmark your program. Determine how fast your program works and how fast you want it to work. Then try to find ways to optimise it, if you fail then post your code, tell how fast you want it to be and what you tried to achieve this.

Comment: Ok my new idea is make own "binary" on strings and I'm going to try it ;D

Comment: You can try to read this paper http://www.math.mcgill.ca/haron/Papers/Journal/coolTOCS.pdf

Comment: Since you're writing all these results somewhere, by far the slowest thing will be your I/O. The most efficient thing would be to asynchronously write one result as you are calculating the next. In that scenario it's almost irrelevant how fast your algorithm is to generate the string as even the slowest is still likely orders of magnitude faster than the I/O.

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see any "decimal" as you described. It looks like you are manually doing binary arithmetic using strings. 

In general, for computers, math and logic is fast, I/O, memory allocation and copying is slow. So try to avoid string manipulation because it tends to have lots of the slow things. For example even [accessing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.chars?view=netframework-4.7.2#performance-and-character-based-indexing) a character from a string builder is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically how to generate a n characters deep / long sequence with all possible combinations of zeroes and ones. This question has an answer already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078549/generate-sequence-a-to-z-and-then-0-to-9-from-a-to-999/41078635#41078635).

Adapting it to your requirements is easy: `GetNthEnumeration(new[] { "0", "1" }, 3).ToList();`

Comment: Thx, it seems that my  is faster...for 20bites I get results:  ElapsedMine=00:00:00.6530281
ElapsedRecursive=00:00:01.8145570

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use to do this pretty cleanly:

Let's say you want all combinations of the bits turned on for a number "bits"

```
bits = 1111
combination = bits
rv = [bits]
while n != 0:
    combination = (combination - 1) & bits
    rv.append(combination)
return rv
```

This will give you every combination of whatever bits are set in "bits". This doesn't need to be a full sequence of 1 bits either. If you used bits = 1010 it will only return 1010, 1000, 0010, 0000

If the "bits" consists of only 1's then you're basically subtracting down to zero from the original number by counting 1 at a time. (i.e. & with 1111 doesn't really do anything)